# how create array in multiselect checkbox value in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Here i want to do , if user select the **Launched** and **Ready To move** means i want to take that value and send this value in array format to next page through AJAX url, here i take that value but can't create array format ,

```js
$("#fullSearch_btn").click(function(){
    var items = [];
    $('#property_status:checked').each(function(){ items.push($(this).val()); });
    var property_status_result = items.join(', ');
    alert(items);
  
});

$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
        url:"http://domain.com/api/get/areas/city?cityId="+city_id,
        success: function(data) {
            //console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(exception){
        alert('Exeption:'+exception);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="button-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:100%;text-align:left; border-radius: 0px;">Property Status <span class="caret" style="text-align:right;margin-left: 50px;"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="property_status" name="property_status[]" value="Launched" />&nbsp;Launched</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="property_status" name="property_status[]" value="Ready To move" />&nbsp;Ready To move</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1"><input type="checkbox" id="property_status" name="property_status[]" value="Under Construction" />&nbsp;Under Construction</a></li>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" id="fullSearch_btn">
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly, IDs must be unique on document context

Comment: Use class name in place of ID and you should also use checkbox tag outside the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use split function instead() of join()

```
var property_status_result = items.split(',');
```

Comment: i need like this [ { "Launched" : "Ready To move"}]

Comment: If you want like this "["Launched","Ready To move","Under Construction"]" the you can use ` var property_status_result = JSON.stringify(items.split(',')); `

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments say, change your IDs. As for sending an array, you can do this:

```
var items = [];
$('.dropdown-menu input').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    items.push($(this).val());
  }
});
var property_status_result = items.join(', ');
alert(items);
```

But that creates a string of array items. Is that what you need?

Comment: i need like this [ { "Launched" : "Ready To move"}]

Comment: That is an object inside an array. The first item needs to be a key, more likely you need something like this `[{value: "Launched"}, {value: "Ready To move"}]`. But that can't be sent in the URL parameter. Maybe send it in `data` attribute?
Also, if you need your form you can do with an if so it can look like this `[{Launched: "Ready To move"}]`.

 Can you give me an example of what data can the API interpret? Maybe I can solve it that way :)

Comment: I am doing property search, they return the values like this [ {
  "createdBy" : "agent",
  "createdDate" : "2016-09-20T08:13:30.418Z",
  "property_status" : [ Launched, "Ready To move ],
  }
  ]

Comment: You should stringify it like @Abhay suggested. It should be just the format you need and you can use it later to check it.